# Canonical ordering of days of week

Tags: sorting

The entities representing the days of the week sort alphabetically:

```
Sort[{Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday}]

(* {Friday, Monday, Saturday, Sunday, Thursday, Tuesday, Wednesday} *)
```

(Note that these are not strings.)

Is there a better way to sort than using the following?

```
SortBy[PositionIndex[{Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday}]]
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be ill-defined because it is cyclic? I guess you could order them if you agree on which day is the first of the week… some say monday, others sunday…

Comment: "Canonically" (i.e. according to the Bible) the first day was Sunday.

Comment: I don't know if you can get more canonical than the Bible, but according to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), the week begins on Monday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not much shorter than your `PositionIndex[{Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday}]`, but you can also  use `` System`DateObjectDump`$dowAssociation ``:

```
System`DateObjectDump`$dowAssociation
```

> <|Monday -> 1, Tuesday -> 2, Wednesday -> 3, Thursday -> 4, 
>    Friday -> 5, Saturday -> 6, Sunday -> 7|>

```
sortByDoW = SortBy[System`DateObjectDump`$dowAssociation];
```

**Examples:**

```
sortByDoW @ {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday}
```

> {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday}

```
sortByDoW @ RandomSample[{Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday}]
```

> {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday}

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a better way to sort than using the following?
>
> `SortBy[PositionIndex[{Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday}]]`

No, that is the best method.

Note that the accepted answer for this question references a private variable that disappeared around version 12.1 or 12.2

Answer (score 3):

As you've noticed, the weekday symbols are by default sorted by their symbol names. This is because `Monday`,... are not true date specifications, but only day types. So there is not really a canonical ordering. However, you could do the following:

```
SortBy[DayPlus[DayPlus[Today, 1, Sunday], 1, #] &]@
  {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday}
(* {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday} *)
```

This works by converting the day types into actual dates. This is done in three steps:

- Find the next Sunday after today (you could also hardcode the date of a sunday here, but this is more readable I think)
- Find the date of the first Monday/... after that point
- Sort these dates

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ResourceFunction["SortLike"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SortLike) which sorts a list $l_1$ so it respects the order in second argument $l_2$

```
days = {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday};

SeedRandom[1];
randomdays = RandomChoice[days, 20]

(* {Sunday, Friday, Wednesday, Friday, Monday, Tuesday, Sunday, Monday, 
Monday, Wednesday, Monday, Sunday, Monday, Thursday, Saturday, 
Wednesday, Monday, Thursday, Friday, Friday} *)

ResourceFunction["SortLike"][randomdays, days]

(* {Monday, Monday, Monday, Monday, Monday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, 
Wednesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Thursday, Friday, Friday, Friday, 
Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Sunday, Sunday} *)
```